# How to Change textbox on combobox selection while adding table rows in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that adds rows dynamically, it has a selection box that changes the value of a textbox when the onchange function is fired but the problem is that it resets all the textboxes value instead of that particular empty one when a new row is added.How do you make it change accordingly.

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', 'select.products', function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $(".price").val(selected);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.addProduct', function(){
        var ele = $(this).parents('tr').clone();
        ele.find('input[type=text]').val('');
        $(this).parents('tr').after(ele);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.delProduct', function(){
        if($(this).parents('table').find('tr').length > 2) {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="addProducts" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>POI</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Add Rows?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td> 
        <td><input size=25 type="text" class="price" readonly=true/></td>
        <td>
            <select name="selRow0" class="products">
                <option value="500">Product 1</option>
                <option value="200">Product 2</option>
                <option value="450">Product 3</option>
            </select>   
        </td>   
        <td><input type="button" class="delProduct" value="Delete" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="addProduct" value="AddMore" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="shw"></div>
```

Please see the fiddle below thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/josephat/xd7zknyc/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gone through your JS Fiddle Link.You need to change the value to a specific row by getting the current column reference using jquery closest.

The Solution Is , Change the below code and try :

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('change', 'select.products', function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    //$(".price").val(selected);
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".price").val(selected);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.addProduct', function(){
    var ele = $(this).parents('tr').clone();
    ele.find('input[type=text]').val('');
    $(this).parents('tr').after(ele);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.delProduct', function(){
    if($(this).parents('table').find('tr').length > 2) {
      $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="addProducts" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>POI</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Add Rows?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td> 
                <td><input size=25 type="text" class="price" readonly=true/></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="selRow0" class="products">
                        <option value="500">Product 1</option>
                        <option value="200">Product 2</option>
                         <option value="450">Product 3</option>
                    </select>   
                </td>   
                <td><input type="button" class="delProduct" value="Delete" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="addProduct" value="AddMore" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="shw"></div>
```

Comment: Try Run Code Snippet and check...It is Solved.

Comment: give me rating for the answer...Thanks.

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: click on UpVote icon.

Comment: which you can see on left side of the answer (up and  down arrows). Just click on up arrow.Thanks.

Comment: used a part of your code and my issue for resolved, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to generate the whole tr with different id's for price text box that will match the drop down option id/name and then update according to this id.

If you want quick solution then replace you change event with following

```
   $(document).on('change', 'select.products', function(event){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $(event.target.parentNode.parentNode).find(".price")[0].value = selected;
      });
```